# Hard float abi selected but soft float library used by GCC on STM32

Tags: gcc, floating-point, stm32

I'm developping on a STM32L4 that embeds a FPv4-SP FPU.
I'm testing the FPU usage. I am compiling using hard float abi:

```
arm-atollic-eabi-gcc -c  (...)  __VFP_FP__ -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard xxx.o  -o xxx.o xxx.c
```

(I've added the same option -mfloat-abi to the link command, even though I don't think it is useful)

However, looking to assembly code, I noticed that software floating point library functions are called:

```
35          volatile float f = 0.125;
0800a2b4:   mov.w   r3, #1040187392 ; 0x3e000000
0800a2b8:   str     r3, [r7, #4]
37          f = f/0.4;
0800a2ba:   ldr     r3, [r7, #4]
0800a2bc:   mov     r0, r3
0800a2be:   bl      0x8000348 <__extendsfdf2>
0800a2c2:   add     r3, pc, #100    ; (adr r3, 0x800a328 <csem_tests+136>)
0800a2c4:   ldrd    r2, r3, [r3]
0800a2c8:   bl      0x8000644 <__divdf3>
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if answering my own question is the right way to go, sorry for inconvenience if it isn't, but I guess it is better than deleting the post.

I've found the issue: the float variable I used for testing was in fact casted to double, and since the FPU is single precision only, the operation was handled in software. Forcing the variable to float like this :

```
float f = (float)0.125;
f = f/(float)0.68768;
```

solved the issue, even if I don't really understand why the compiler casted this variable to double.

Comment: You can simply write `0.125f` and `0.68768f`. As defined in the C grammar, `0.125` and `.068768` are `double` constants. The `f` suffix makes them `float` constants. Using `float` constants is preferable, since the compiler should then convert the decimal source text directly to a `float` value. With a cast of a `double` constant, the compiler must first interpret the source text as a `double` and then convert it to `float`.

Answer (score 3):

because string constants are always double (and all operations are done on double if one of the operands is double) unless you use the 'f' suffix - `0.125f`or command line option `-fsingle-precision-constant`.

If you want a "pure" FPU code you need to use  `-ffast-math` & `-fno-math-errno` as well

Comment: What is the basis for asserting that `-ffast-math` and `-fno-math-errno` are necessary?

Comment: @EricPostpischil - `-fno-math-errno` & `-ffast-math` are needed for example to compile call to the `sqrtf` function to the single  `vsqrt.f32` ARM instruction. So I wrote "pure" FPU code without the wrappers. What is the basis? Experience & gcc documentation + analyses of the generated code with different settings

Comment: If the switches are not used, is the result a call to a `sqrtf` routine that uses a hardware square root instruction but also provides a test for a negative operand (and returns an error in `errno` in that case) and possibly other massaging or is the result a call to a `sqrtf` routine that uses software floating-point?

Comment: Yes - but exact implementation depends on the toolchain. if your compiles was compiled with the multilib option and you compile with the hardware floating point the sqrt will be calculated by the hardware sqrtf inside the wrapper function. You need to experiment and see how it is done  exactly  in your toolchain. personally usually I do not care too much about the parameter checks when I use floats on uCs as do not make any real numeric calculations.